# In X-Bar theory, what could the Specifiers of PPs and AdvPs ever be?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory

In X-Bar theory, do prepositional phrases, adverbial phrases, adjectival phrases etc. ever have specifiers? What could they be?

The only phrases I know the possible specifiers for are: Noun Phrases, which have determiners as their specifiers; and inflectional phrases, which have subjects as their specifiers. What other specifiers may exist in X-bar theory?